# How to add translate="no" via JS to a dynamic translation script?

Tags: javascript, html, translation

I have a script on my website that translates the text contained within a span when the user mouses over an anchor, and it works just fine. However, browsers that do auto-translation seem to be grabbing the titles that get generated onmouseover and translating them as well, which defeats the purpose of the script. I have tried adding the property **translate="no"** to the generated text using JS (as seen below in Line 10) but I must be missing something, because it doesn't seem to be having an effect.

Please help?

JS:

```
$.each($("li"), function(i, elements) {
var links = elements.getElementsByTagName("a");
var article_title = elements.getElementsByClassName("article-title")[0];
$.each(links, function(j, link) {
    var previous_title = article_title.innerHTML;
    if (!$(link).is('.newspaper, .doi')) {
        link.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            $(article_title).fadeTo(150, 0.5, function() {
                article_title.innerHTML = link.title;
                $(article_title).prop('translate', 'no');
                $(article_title).fadeTo(150, 1, function() {});
            });
        });
        link.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
            $(article_title).fadeTo(150, 0.5, function() {
                article_title.innerHTML = previous_title;
                $(article_title).fadeTo(150, 1, function() {});
            });
        });
    }
});
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<li>
      <a href="doc-EN.pdf" title="This is an example" hreflang="en" class="pdf">[EN]</a>
      <a href="doc-ES.pdf" title="Este es un ejemplo" hreflang="es" class="pdf">[ES]</a>
      <span class="article-title">This is an example</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, are you sure that the script interprets

```
translate="no"
```

Property correctly? As in, it figures that this should not be translated? Maybe the code logic appears to be the culprit.

Second, try using .attr instead of .prop?